# Convert Timestamp from Database to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, database, timestamp

I am querying data from a database and want to convert a Database Timestamp to a java.sql.Timestamp:

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SELECT_ALL_DATA);    
    for(Map row : rows) {
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.setMaturityDate(new Timestamp((Long) row.get("MATURTIY_DATE")));
    }
```

However, doing it like that gives me:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

I also tried it without the cast to `Long`, but this gives me:

```
The constructor Timestamp(Object) is undefined
```

Any recommendations how to cast the database object?

I appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new timestamp instance because it is already returned one:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SELECT_ALL_DATA);    
for(Map row : rows) {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setMaturityDate((Timestamp)row.get("MATURTIY_DATE"));
}
```